# Intermediate Gradient during Optimization

Tags: gpflow

While training a GP model with GPFlow I am interested in observing the gradients given to the ScipyOptimizer. I would like to cross-reference these gradients with other GP models. Would anyone have any recommendations as to how to output these tensors before they are handed of to the optimizer?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way of achieving this without hacking the gpflow source code. The easiest solution is probably to edit the `loss_grad_func_wrapper` function defined inside `ScipyOptimizerInterface._minimize` in gpflow/training/external_optimizer.py - it's got the values of all trainable parameters `x`, the loss, and the gradients - though note that these are the *packed* parameters (i.e. a single array of all parameters) - you'll have to manually split them into values/gradients per tensor... or hack the `eval_func(x)` in the `ExternalOptimizerInterface`, which does the unpacking, updates the feed_dict, runs the gradient calculation, and packs the results... I hope this gives you a starting point at least!